# Set option selected with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a situation where I need to use jQuery to initialize a selected option within a select (United States within the Country dropdown). Unfortunately I can't set it within the HTML due to limitations of the platform, and there aren't any classes or ids to target. This form also changes based on ajax (there are 3 versions of the same form based on whether the person is a guest, registering while checking out, or is already registered). The current script I've created works, but won't let you change to another country:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess( function() {
   $('option:contains("United States"):not(:contains("Minor"))').prop("selected", true);
});
```

So basically while it sets it as selected, it does not allow the user to change from the United States options. It appears the Ajax might be reloading every time an option is set for what ever reason.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you unable to open the dropdown? Is there nothing else in the dropdown? Or will it not save the selected item from the dropdown?

Comment: @amflare I am able to open it, all the options are there and I'm able to select a new country, however that selection doesn't remain, it immediately goes back to the United States being selected.

Comment: @amflare, this is currently the only dropdown in the menu (the state option changes from a textbox to a dropdown if united states is selected normally, so far it is not doing that with the united states preselected), it seems that the form is reloading or something when something is selected in the dropbox, perhaps triggering the `ajaxSuccess` causing it to reselect the united states all over again.

Comment: Put some alerts or console.logs in the `ajaxSuccess` and see if they get triggered again

Comment: @amflare, a console.log returns when ever the drop down is changed. I cannot modify that so the question now becomes what can I do to make these changes after the ajaxSuccess fires the first time, but not thereafter? Thank you for your help with this by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, based on the comments it seems that every time you try to change the dropdown, more AJAX is called. In turn, this calls your $.ajaxSuccess function. This means it gets reset on every single AJAX call!

You could do something like this:

```
var set = false;
$(document).ajaxSuccess( function() {
   if (set) return;
   $('option:contains("United States"):not(:contains("Minor"))').prop("selected", true);
   set = true;
});
```

Or, you could take advantage of the arguments passed to `ajaxSuccess` to determine if the code should even be run. For example:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess( function(event, xhr, options) {
   if (xhr.url !== 'the url im listening for') return;
   $('option:contains("United States"):not(:contains("Minor"))').prop("selected", true);
});
```

That approach will only work if there is one particular URL you are listening for of course, but you get the idea. Just make sure that ajaxSuccess function *only when* it is needed to be.

Comment: `if (!set) { //other two lines of code }` is a touch more intuitive. But yes, I have done this on many occasions. It works great.

Comment: The first block worked perfectly. A simple answer that I'm sure I'll hate myself for not figuring out on my own later. Thanks!

Comment: @amflare perhaps, different strokes for different blokes :)

Comment: @Amleonard fair enough :D